# How to sum up every 3 rows by column in Pandas Dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `top3` with data as in the image below.

[image: Data table from PANDAS in jupyter notebook]

Using the two columns, STNAME and SENSUS2010POP, I need to find the sum for Wyoming (sum: 91738+75450+46133=213321), then the sum for Wisconsin (sum:1825699), West Virginia and so on. Summing up the 3 counties  for each state. (and need to sort them in ascending order after that).

I have tried this code to compute the answer:

```py
topres=top3.groupby('STNAME').sum().sort_values(['CENSUS2010POP'], ascending=False)
```

Maybe you can suggest a more efficient way to do it? Maybe with a lambda expression?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share some of your codes? SO is the place to guide you into the right direction, rather than do the whole thing for you...

Comment: I have tried topresults =top3.nlargest(3,'CENSUS2010POP').sum(), however, this only sums up the first top 3 states..  any pointers in the right direction?  
 I'd be grateful.

Comment: @MariaBruevich if you edit a question after it has been answered, using a solution that has been proposed, please add first a line that specify you edited the question and why, something like: "EDIT: I tried this solution..." so that users know what that something was added afterwards.

Comment: @MariaBruevich there is not a more efficient solution than using a core `pandas` feature. That's the purpose of `groupby`. 
If you find a solution proposed by someone useful, mark it as an accepted answer by clicking on the gray check mark beside the answer. See this for more info on how to deal with answers to your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('STNAME').sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm starting in the problem before selecting the top 3 counties per state, and jumping straight to their sum.

I found it helpful with this problem to use a list selection.

I created a data frame view of the counties with:

```
counties_df=census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50]
```

and a separate one of the states so I could get at their names.

```
states_df=census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 40]
```

Then I was able to create that sum of the populations of the top 3 counties per state, by looping over all states and summing the largest 3.

```
res = [(x, counties_df[(counties_df['STNAME']==x)].nlargest(3,['CENSUS2010POP'])['CENSUS2010POP'].sum()) for x in states_df['STNAME']]
```

I converted that result to a data frame

```
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

named its columns

```
   dfObj.columns = ['STNAME','POP3']
```

sorted in place

```
dfObj.sort_values(by=['POP3'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
```

and returned the first 3

```
return dfObj['STNAME'].head(3).tolist()
```

Definitely `groupby` is a more compact way to do the above, but I found this way helped me break down the steps (and the associated course had not yet dealt with groupby).